# How to best obfuscate a built-in key in an application?

Tags: c++, authentication, encryption, passwords, cryptography

We're building an application that needs to log into a website using built-in credentials. It's not optimal to say the least, but we're stuck with "knowing" the username and password beforehand (hence stick them into the application somehow) and can not rely on runtime user information.

So I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484440/saving-passwords-inside-an-application) stack overflow article which basically represents my case and the answer seems to indicate that best possible approach is to at least encrypt the password with a known key and to store this key in the application in an obfuscated way. My follow up question now is: How do I best obfuscate this key so that it isn't visible in a file dump of the executable? Are there best practices for that as well?

Comment: There are commercial "exe packer" tools which can do this, as well as various "DRM" solutions; it's how game developers and others do anti-cheating and licensing control.

Comment: @pjc50 Are there also non commercial conan-ready libraries that you know of?

Comment: How about using a key that looks like the result of compiling some code? Just hide it in plain sight.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That sounds like a plan. This + openssl to encrypt the password is by now my best bet.

Comment: You can never truly trust something that's run on someone else's machine and someone else's network. They could be capturing the communication, or decompiling your application or... A safer bet would be to openly use credentials that the user is aware of, as this wouldn't need to be kept a secret. That being said, it's unclear exactly what your reasoning is for needing these hardcoded credentials, making it hard to understand exactly how and if this is an XY problem and what could be a better solution.

Comment: In which environment is the application installed? Some desktop application running within a companies network? An embedded application - which runs on smart-home devices? A mobile phone application on private phones? What kind of users do you expect? There is no "general best practice" - except the best pratice to adapt your amount of effort for obfuscating a key to your audience.

Comment: @DocBrown The app will be deployed on foreign servers that we don't really know how serious their security/protection efforts are. So it's a big risk anyway but they pay good...

Comment: @glades: ok, so a B2B scenario. Why on earth isn't the server operator allowed to *know* the credentials - or configure them by themselves? What will they do when your application cannot contact the website any more because the other side has changed the credentials? What will they do if this happens and your company does not exist anymore, noone be able to do any maintenance? I have seen these " hidden credentials" scenario so often causing unforeseen issues that I would heavily recommend to find a way which avoids what you are trying.

Comment: No response to my former question? Lost interest? It could really help to get better answers if you explain us the operational surroundings and contraints, as I asked above.

Comment: @DocBrown True. The point is more that we're deploying overseas in countries that are not really known for their high security standards. The relationship is actually more like: We (A) have a customer (B) that employs a cloud service provider (C) which is responsible for running our services for B. Now what happens if an employee of C tempers with our services or there is a root break in C? Currently our API allows admin access over REST to temper with our internal backend. Say we have not enough time to implement full user management on our side, how do we go about it?

Comment: @glades: in your question, you mention an application and a website. In your former comment, you talk about "your services" and "your internal backend". Can you please explain what is what - are "your service" the application or the website? Is "the website" = "your internal backend"? It is really hard to follow you when you mix up different terms. I am specifically interested in which of the components you have under your control, and which not.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be aware of the caveats in the comments already given, and experience has shown that even strong obfuscation of built-in keys is not safe if an application is widely distributed and there is something of value to gain from cracking it.

That said, if you're OK with credentials being present in the running application where a debugger may find them, a possible mechanism would be to code a computation that returns a fixed result (for example by hashing the concatenation of the application name and an unchanging part of some help text), and use this as the key to decrypt the actual credentials, which may be stored in encrypted form within the executable or in a configuration file.

I'm currently using such a scheme to store database credentials in an internal-use application. Distribution of this application is strictly limited to in-house users, and most users use it on locked-down terminal servers where debugging or reverse engineering tools are not available and can't be installed by users.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously this isn't ideal, but you know that already. If you're not sure about their security you'll at least want them to have their own set of credentials so that you can invalidate them if they become compromised so that it doesn't put your servers at risk.

That said a slightly alternate approach you might want to consider is using the OS's native credential storage system. Windows for example has CredRead* functions that lock credentials to a user account. During the install process you could have them enter the user/pass and store it there (or possibly have the installer do it automatically), making it available to the windows user account the server is running under. It would not be accessible outside of that account.